# How to ignore invalid dropping st:0 that broke the stream

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I am using ffmpeg to capture live stream in flv format 'there is m3u8 format' and restreamed to Youtube, my problem is when i run the code above the ffmpeg keep stuck on  'invalid dropping st:0' and that broke the stream.

Is there a way to ignore those dropped frames , or at least stop ffmpeg and I will loop it to keep the stream running, by reading the output log so when there is dropped frame I will close ffmpeg and run it again.

The second question is it possible to capture the live flv stream and save it in flv file and made some deley after that i will restream it again to youtube
live stream in FLV fromat ----> save it in file -----> wait 1 min ------> stream the saved file to youtube this is the code i use :

```
#!/bin/bash
u="https://pull-flv-l11-va01.xxxxxxxx.com/stage/stream-2995889464288477225_ld.flv"

key_stream="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz"
trap printout SIGINT
printout() {
    echo ""
    echo "Finished with count=$count"
    exit
}
while :
do
    ((count++))

ffmpeg  -i $u \
-c:v libx264 -b:a 384k -ac 2 -preset slow -crf 28 \
-profile:v high -bf 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-threads 4 -xerror \
-maxrate 5M -bufsize 10M -r 30 -g 15 -coder 1 -f flv $key_stream

    sleep 1
done
```

1. Read the log of ffmpeg and close it it immediatly when dropped frames appeared and run it again
2. Using a file to store the coming stream and restreamed, but I wish to keep that file in small size because the stream is too long
3. The best solution is to just ignore those frames or replace them with black pic to keep the live stream running

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Link to report.

Comment: what you mean ??

Comment: In your ffmpeg command, add -report and rerun. Upload and link to report.